# Adding email to adauth is causing an 'undefined method 'mail'' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to be able to get the email from active directory when using adauth.

Rails 4.x, ruby 2.0

If I add the mapping for email in user.rb, I get an error of

> NoMethodError in SessionsController#create undefined method `mail' for
>
> Rails.root: C:/Users/cmendla/RubymineProjects/technical_library
>
> Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
>   app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:17:in `create'

```
user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 include Adauth::Rails::ModelBridge
  Adauth.add_field(Adauth::AdObjects::User, :mail, :mail)


  AdauthMappings = {
      :login => :login,                #was login  login
      :group_strings => :cn_groups,
      :ou_strings => :dn_ous,
      :email => :mail,
      :name => :name,

  }

  AdauthSearchField = [:login, :login]

  def groups
    group_strings.split(", ")
  end


end
```

Params from User_controller.rb

```
 Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
      def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:login,
                               :group_strings,
                               :name,
                               :ou_strings,
                               :email
  )
end
```

sessions_controller.rb - create:

```
def create
        ldap_user = Adauth.authenticate(params[:username], params[:password])
        #           byebug

        if ldap_user

            user = User.return_and_create_from_adauth(ldap_user)
            session[:user_id] = user.id
            redirect_to home_path, :notice => "You are now logged in "
            # byebug
        else
            redirect_to '/signin', :notice => "Invalid Login"
        end
    end
```

schema for users:

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "login"
    t.text     "group_strings"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "ou_strings"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
    t.string   "email"
  end
```

If I take the email mapping out, adauth works fine.

Comment: It happens to me too when User object don't have mail